# elasticsearch migration plugin: Blank page

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

In order to upgrade our 1.5.2 elasticsearch to 2.x, I have successfully installed elasticsearch migration plugin v1.18, but when linking to http://localhost:9200/_plugin/migration/ I get a blank page.

Also the next command gives me nothing:
`~/bin/elasticsearch-1.5.2$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_plugin/migration/`

What am I missing?

Comment: Issue was with the port. It worked with 9201

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the plugin as root?

Check the permissions of /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/migration. Your default umask may prevent the elasticsearch user to read the contents.

This fixed it for me:

```
chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
```

Comment: Thanks Nils, the issue was with the port. It worked with 9201. see my discussion with elastic team at: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-migration-plugin-blank-page/55163