# Elasticsearch Migration Plugin installation steps

Tags: elasticsearch

In order to upgrade  2.3.z elasticsearch to 5.x, I have successfully installed elasticsearch migration plugin, but when linking to http://localhost:9200/_plugin/elasticsearch-migration/ I get a blank page.

Can someone let me know the following:-

1. Do I have to install the plugin all the machines in the cluster?
2. Do I have to restart all the machines in the cluster?

I have already tried the steps as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914216/785523). But still I am getting a blank page.

Comment: Answer is here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-migration-plugin-installation-steps/103160/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [elastic community](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-migration-plugin-installation-steps/103160)

1. Plugin is not needed to be installed in all the nodes. Only one node is sufficient.
2. Restart of node or cluster is not needed.